# nftables multiple input chains not working

Tags: ubuntu, debian, redhat, firewall, nftables

So I have two input chains, `input` and `dyn` which is dynamically generated.

However the rules of `dyn` just don't work because of `input`. I've tried setting the priority of `input` to `1`, and the `dyn` to `0` even `-200`. Still nothing.

When I flush the `input` rules, then `dyn` works.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
sudo nft list ruleset
table inet filter {
chain input {
    type filter hook input priority filter + 1; policy accept;
    iif "lo" accept
    ct state established,related accept
    tcp dport 299 ip saddr 3x.xx.xx.xx accept
    icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, packet-too-big, time-exceeded, parameter-problem, echo-request, echo-reply, nd-router-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-neighbor-advert, 148, 149 } accept
    ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type { mld-listener-query, mld-listener-report, mld-listener-done, mld2-listener-report, 151, 152, 153 } accept
    counter packets 10 bytes 5255 drop
}

chain dyn {
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
    iif "lo" accept
    ct state established,related accept
    ip saddr 2x.xx.xx.xx udp dport 8999 log prefix "dyn" accept
    ip6 saddr xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::9999 udp dport 8999 log prefix "dyn" accept
    ip saddr 2x.xx.xx.xx tcp dport 7999 log prefix "dyn" accept
    ip6 saddr xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::9999 tcp dport 7999 log prefix "dyn" accept
    ip saddr 2x.xx.xx.xx icmp type echo-request log prefix "dyn" accept
    ip6 saddr xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::9999 icmp type echo-request log prefix "dyn"
    ip saddr 2x.xx.xx.xx tcp dport 6999 log prefix "dyn" accept
    ip6 saddr xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::aaaa tcp dport 6999 log prefix "dyn" accept
}
}
```